Dedicated IP vs CDN
In times of shared hosting, it was a real plus point for Google, if a site has a dedicated IP address.
What changed in this terms in the current time, where sites are hosted in the cloud and run through CDN nodes?

See https://www.seroundtable.com/sharing-ip-addresses-shared-servers-google-seo-37171.html and https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/core-web-vitals (can't really get good metrics without a CDN)

@Martheen the first one is good
